# how to read xml file without root element in ios

Tags: ios, xml, xml-parsing

I have and XML file which have no root element. I have tried XMLParser.h - XMLParser.m file and XMLReader.h - XMLReader.m . But I am not able read all my element. It just read the first element. Can you please help me to solve this?

My XML file is like

```
<Firstname>First</Firstname>
<Lastname>Last</Lastname>
<Contactnumber>123456</Contactnumber>
<Address>Address of the person</Address>
```

I have tried NSXMLParser also but all just read my first element. that is just

```
 <Firstname>First<Firstname>
```

How can I solved this? How can I Read all the element?

Here is the Methods used for XML reading

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@" ,elementName,namespaceURI,qualifiedName,currentElementValue,attributeDict);


//NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundAttributeDeclarationWithName:(NSString *)attributeName forElement:(NSString *)elementName type:(NSString *)type defaultValue:(NSString *)defaultValue
{
NSLog(@"element name -- %@ attribute -%@",elementName, attributeName);

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 

if(!currentElementValue) 
    currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
else
    [currentElementValue appendString:string];

NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);

}
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{

}
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{

}
// sent when the parser has completed parsing. If this is encountered, the parse was successful.
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{


if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"affiliate_name"]) {
    NSLog(@"Done --- ");
}

NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@",elementName,namespaceURI,qName,currentElementValue);

defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


[defaults setObject:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


 }
```

Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: XML without a root element is invalid XML.

Comment: I wonder if you could insert a fake root element around your XML before validating?

Comment: At the point of parsing do you have a string representing the XML?

Comment: I know this is wrong XML but I am getting this XML only. I have to parse this and save those data to user defaults, Can I do this?

Comment: I am not getting by "string representing the XML". Can you please explain?

Comment: Can I add Root element before parsing it? How can I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59709/discussion-between-nsp-and-sachin-kainth).